# Is there any T4 Editor for Visual Studio 2010 CTP2?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor, t4, clarius-visual-t4

i am looking for a T4 Editor for VS 2010 CTP2. Clarius states on their Blog they are waiting for the Beta1.

Any idea other idea where to look?

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 1):

yes there is another T4 Editor developed by tangible engineering.
It runs on VS 2008. They also just released a version for VS 2010 CTP2.

You can get the VS2008 here: t4editor.tangible-engineering.com

and the VS 2010 CTP2 version here: tangibleengineering.blogspot.com

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an [updated version for VS2010 Beta 1](http://tangibleengineering.blogspot.com/2009/05/tangible-t4-editor-for-visual-studio.html)